# Shared options between targets and running multiple targets

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs

I'm a bit confused about grunt. First, I'm in love with this tool but the documentation (or maybe it's just me) it's not very clever about this.

So I have something like this:

```
coffee:
  options:
    sourceMap: true
    files: [{
      expand: true
      cwd:    '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts'
      src:    '{,*/}*.coffee'
      dest:   '<%= yeoman.tmp %>/scripts'
      ext:    '.js'
    }]
  test:
    files: [{
      expand: true
      cwd:    '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts'
      src:    '{,*/}*.coffee'
      dest:   '<%= yeoman.tmp %>/scripts'
      ext:    '.js'
    }, {
      expand: true
      cwd:    '<%= yeoman.test %>/spec'
      src:    '{,*/}*.coffee'
      dest:   '<%= yeoman.tmp %>/spec'
      ext:    '.js'
    }]
```

I thought that this in theory should have "shared" files between my target "dev", "dist" and "test" have the custom one.

However from what I've understood, `files` should not stay under options (why?).
I have also this one:

```
compass:
  all:
    options:
      sassDir:                 '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles'
      cssDir:                  '<%= yeoman.tmp %>/styles'
      generatedImagesDir:      '<%= yeoman.tmp %>/images/generated'
      imagesDir:               '<%= yeoman.app %>/images'
      javascriptsDir:          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts'
      fontsDir:                '<%= yeoman.app %>/fonts'
      importPath:              [
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components'
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles'
      ]
      httpImagesPath:          '/images'
      httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated'
      httpFontsPath:           '/fonts'
      httpStylesheetsPath:     '/styles'
      httpJavascriptsPath:     '/scripts'
      relativeAssets:          true
      assetCacheBuster:        false
      bundleExec:              true
      raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
  dist:
    options:
      environment:        'production'
      generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
```

but running `grunt compass` run **both** `grunt compass:all` and `grunt compass:dist` is this normal behavior?

I definitely need a better explaination about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first level in a Task config can be a "sub"-task.

So you can call it in the following ways:

```
grunt compass

grunt compass:all

grunt compass:dist
```

When you don't reference to a sub-task grunt runs all the subtask's of the given main task. (So the first runs `all` and `dist` either.

Otherwise you can reference in your config to other sections with these '<%= ... %>' notations. Details: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config

Comment: Thanks Lajos, I want to ask other few details but your answer is already ok. Should the `files` key stay under `options` or it's different for each plugin?

Comment: options is the default for all subtasks, but you can overwrite it with the subtasks options. As far as I know files is not special, so you can use it in the upper options as a default for the subtasks, but you can define it only in the subtasks